# Reinitialize Parse iOS SDK with a new server URL

Tags: ios, parse-server

I'm wondering if there is some way to stop the Parse client and reinitialize it with a new server URL. I'm not seeing any method to do so, so I don't have any attempts to show.

My use case is this: I have two main segments of my users, customers and providers. They use the app pretty differently, and we think as we scale, we could benefit from hosting the backend on different servers connected to the same database, so that we can use the most cost efficient machines and configurations for each case on AWS.

However, we currently use one app, and just send the user to the appropriate side of the app when they login. Ideally, we'd like to not have to re-work entirely to release two separate apps, one for customers and one for providers.

I would like to have a third separate login server, which will be what is initialized when the app is first opened. Once a user logs in, it would fetch their user, then re-initialize the Parse client to one of the other servers depending on whether the user was a customer or provider.

Is this feasible at all with the current SDK, or is the only way to have separate backend servers going to be to have separate client side apps as well?

Comment: did you find out if this was possible?

Comment: I never got any responses about it, but looking at the `Parse.h` header file in `Parse.framework`, there's a note for the `initializeWithConfiguration` method that says "Re-setting the configuration after having previously sent requests through the SDK results in undefined behavior."  It doesn't seem to be advised, and even if you found something that works it could change without notice in a later release since the behavior is currently undefined.